# pdfjs-dist bower and gulp concatenation and minification silently fail

Tags: gulp, bower, gulp-uglify, pdf.js

I'm using pdf.js in an angular project. Building with gulp in production mode works fine, but the production build produces non-working code that fails silently without and warnings or errors, whatsoever. I never get a viewer canvas.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the problem lies not with minification, but rather with concatenation.
The dist directory of the pdfjs-dist bower package contains three files:

- pdf.js
- pdf.worker.js
- pdf.combined.js

the `bower.json` file list `pdf.js` and `pdf.worker.js`, but when using gulp bower copy and concatenation you should use  `pdf.combined.js` instead of the other two. Add an override to your projects bower.json

```
"overrides": {
   "pdfjs-dist": {
      "main": [
        "build/pdf.combined.js"
      ]
   }
}
```